# How to solve Xamarin Form ListView ViewCell Overlapping Issue?

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.forms, data-binding, frontend

I have a ListView with Customized ViewCell. The binding ItemsSource is a list of Biller Class. The ViewCell overlapping only happened when I'm displaying more than 10 items on the screen and I'm scrolling my screen.

Biller Class Definition

```
public class Biller
{
    public string BillerId { get; set; }
    public string BillerName { get; set; }
    public string BillerShortName { get; set; }
    public string BillerLogoUrl { get; set; }
}
```

Custom ViewCell Definition

```
public class CustomBillCell : ViewCell
    {
        public CustomBillCell()
        {
            // instantiate each of our views
            var billerShortNameLabel = new Label();
            var billerIdLabel = new Label();
            var billerNameLabel = new Label();
            var verticalLayout = new StackLayout();
            var horizontalLayout = new StackLayout();
            var billFrame = new Frame();
            var viewBillButton = new Button
            {
                Text = "View Bill",
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand
            };

            // set bindings
            billerShortNameLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("BillerShortName"));
            billerIdLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("BillerId"));
            billerNameLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("BillerName"));
            viewBillButton.SetBinding(ClassIdProperty, new Binding("BillerName"));
            viewBillButton.Clicked += ViewBillButtonClicked;

            // Set properties for desired design
            billerShortNameLabel.FontSize = 20;
            billerShortNameLabel.FontFamily = "d-din-bold";
            verticalLayout.Children.Add(billerShortNameLabel);
            verticalLayout.Children.Add(billerNameLabel);
            verticalLayout.Children.Add(billerIdLabel);
            verticalLayout.Spacing = 2;
            horizontalLayout.Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal;
            horizontalLayout.Children.Add(verticalLayout);
            horizontalLayout.Children.Add(viewBillButton);

            // Set properties for Frame
            billFrame.HasShadow = false;
            billFrame.CornerRadius = 10;
            billFrame.BorderColor = Color.FromHex("#0C0555");
            billFrame.Content = horizontalLayout;
            billFrame.Margin = 14;

            View = billFrame;
        }

        [Obsolete]
        private async void ViewBillButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var billSignUpPage = new BillSignUpPage();
            Button btn = sender as Button;
            billSignUpPage.BindingContext = btn;
            await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(billSignUpPage);
        }
    }
```

ListView Cell Overlapping Image
[image]

Comment: change the caching strategy of your ListView

Answer (score 3):

This problem should be the cache of `Cell` not recycling, you can set `CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"` for `LsitView` to solve that.

The **[RecycleElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/performance#recycleelement)** caching strategy specifies that the ListView will attempt to minimize its memory footprint and execution speed by recycling list cells. This mode doesn't always offer a performance improvement, and testing should be performed to determine any improvements. However, it's the preferred choice, and should be used in the following circumstances:

- Each cell has a small to moderate number of bindings.
- Each cell's BindingContext defines all of the cell data.
- Each cell is largely similar, with the cell template unchanging.

In **XAML**, set the `CachingStrategy` attribute as shown in the *XAML* below:

```
<ListView CachingStrategy="RecycleElement">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
              ...
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```